# Using jquery to create checkboxes from string

Tags: php, jquery, search, checkbox

I do have a string that contains keywords, like:

```
$keywords = "shoes, bags, shirts, accessoires"
```

I want to have created a list of checkboxes out of this string.
The checkboxes should show up after loading the page and all checkboxes should be checked, like:

```
[x] shoes [x] bags [x] shirts [x] accessoires
```

So user should be able to uncheck some keywords to narrow down search results.

Is this possible with jquery? Thanks,

Comment: This is possible with jQuery. Please post the code you have attempted to solve this problem with youself, as per the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

split up the keywords, and iterate over them creating a label and a checkbox :

```
var keywords = "shoes, bags, shirts, accessoires";

$.each(keywords.split(','), function(_, word) {
    var lbl = $('<label />', {text: word}),
        box = $('<input />', {type: 'checkbox', name: word, checked: 'checked'});

    lbl.prepend(box).appendTo('body');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uvJm2/)

Comment: Thank you. This works great to generate checkboxes. Just don't know how get the $keywords string into jquery as var keywords = $keywords; does not work?!?

Answer (score 0):

```
$keywords = "shoes, bags, shirts, accessoires";

var keyword_array=$keywords.split(",");
var str="";
$.each(keyword_array, function( index, value ) {
str +="<input type='checkbox' >"+ value + "</input>";  

});
```

now use this str to set html by **[html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**

reference **[each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)**

Comment: @Salim in question it is not mention that is is come in php i give my answer by assuming a string which is store in $keywords and we can make same variable in jquery also and thanks for focus

Comment: it is possible @Salim see in javascript--->https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit